# Add XML declaration to XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I created a big XML document using XElement and XAttribute. I did it by adding the attributes to the elements and adding elements to elements.

Like this:

```
// root node: PhysicalProperty
XElement PhysicalProperty = new XElement("PhysicalProperty");

// PhysicalProperty child element: Management
XElement Management = new XElement("Management");
XAttribute ManagementOrganizationName = new XAttribute("OrganizationName", property.Company.Name);
XAttribute ManagementManagementID = new XAttribute("ManagementID", property.Company.CompanyID);
Management.Add(ManagementOrganizationName);
Management.Add(ManagementManagementID);
PhysicalProperty.Add(Management);
```

My XML has a lot of elements. However, I noticed that it did not created the xml declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

It looks like I should have created a XDocument. How can I create the XDocument and add my root element (PhysicalProperty) to the XDocument? Is it possible?

Comment: You should pass `new XAttribute(...)` (etc) directly to the `XElement` constructor, instead of making lots of variables and calling `Add()`.

Comment: Yes, but know it has +30 elements. I was wondering if I can create Document/Declaration and set to my root element

Comment: No, because an element isn't a document. It doesn't make sense to have a declaration for an element - only for a document.

Comment: That's why `XDocument` has a `Declaration` property, but `XElement` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `new XDeclaration(...)` to the `XDocument` constructor, followed by your root element.

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to edit all my XElement. That's what I said. I can't assign to XDocument.Element, can I?

Comment: You can call `Add()` instead of passing the root to the constructor.

Comment: @user6824563 - No reason to "edit all your XElement". Why do you think that?

Comment: Not sure why downvoted, that's valid answer. Maybe adding code example will help with some misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

You must start with an XDocument, which comes with a default declaration member with utf-8 encoding. If you need to, you could replace Declaration with a new instance of this.

```csharp
var fi = new FileInfo(@"[MyFileName]");
var cultureName = "en-CA";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fi.FullName, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
var language = doc.Descendants()
        .Where(t => t.Name.LocalName == "Language")
        .FirstOrDefault();

if (language != null && language.Value != cultureName)
{
    language.SetValue(cultureName);
    File.WriteAllText(fi.FullName
        , $"{doc.Declaration}{doc.ToString()}"
        , encoding: Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

From the document you can search, browse, or create items.
Once you need to store the contents of the XML document as such, with its declaration, you can simply concatenate the declaration when saving the content. The content of the document already includes a line break to incorporate the declaration.